# Swift tableView cell doesnt have a webView member

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I made a custom tableview cell with basic style. I put webView inside content and I'm populating my cell with string on lable (works fine ), but I can't acess webView. 
There is no function on "cell.webView", so i can't populate my view. How can I populate a cell with webView on custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do this:

**Step 1 :** Create a custom cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell`

**Step 2 :** Add a property `webView` in it.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var webView = UIWebView()

    var companyName = UILabel()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code. Add details based on your needs.
        webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)
        contentView.addSubview(webView)
    }
}
```

**Step 3 :** Use `MyTableViewCell` to supply cells for your table view. Simply call `cell.webView` now.

Comment: And what if im not using Tableview class, but instead MyTableViewCell : UIViewController?

Comment: I did not get you. Your custom cell must be subclassing `UITableViewCell ` only.

Comment: I made a table in storyBoard and put label and webView. Now i want populate it with data. Label is working but i can not assign cell to webView. Im not using table view, im using UIViewController and inside a have a custom cell.

Comment: im using this :

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell Result", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
cell.textLabel?.text = dataHistory[indexPath.row]

Comment: Instead of using `UITableViewCell `, as I mentioned above, you would need to create a subclass of it, add your `webView` and then use `MyTableViewCell ` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` function.

Comment: So i need to create a new class like MyTableViewCell above, and set the cell in storyBoard to that class, and then in my main class i should modify this line of code :

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell Result", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
?

Comment: Great... Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.